# Connecting two points with same label using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm doing an MRR (mark-release-recapture) study on an insect. When I collect the insect I take the GPS point and I mark it with a unique number. When I recapture it I'm able to recognize it and I take the second GPS point to know how far it is from the first point. The column has the code of the "name" of the insect collected, for example N1.

I would like to connect the point with the same code N1 (The point where I collect the individual for the first time and all subsequent points where it was captured) to calculate the total distance travelled.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to GIS StackExchange.

You can do this with a points to line workflow.

In QGIS 3 there is a tool in the processing toolbox (accessed from Processing> Toolbox) called "Points to path", which will do this.

Just put the field with the ID (the "Name") that you want to use in the "Group field".

Comment: `Points to path` needs an order field, which tells it in what order to connect the points (EG, draw a line from A to B to C, not A to C to B). If you have a "date of capture" field for each point, you can use that for the order field.